# Wireless connects but does not work

Tags: wireless, 13.10, internet

Strange problem.  Built my laptop (dual with Win7) with 64 bit 13.10 in January of this year.  Added a lot packages (Chrome, LibreOffice, PipeLight w/Wine patches (for NetFlix), et al).  Got everything working.  Never had a problem with wireless.

Got busy doing other stuff and did not boot Linux again till last week.  Now, wireless does not work.  Connects but you can not ping the router.  No changes whatsoever to the Linux build since last used.  Only thing that changed was the Comcast router.  I had to upgrade -- man I hate Comcast.  Anyway, the only difference I found with the router is that it hands out 10. addresses instead of 192.168. addresses out of the box.  I know this as I had some fixed IPs on some PCs and had to change them.  But I can't figure out why my wireless is wacked.  So, before I do anything drastic like rebuilding the whole shebang, I figured, I would ask here and see if anyone can point out what I have overlooked.  I manually copied the scirpt suggested for this type of question:

[Wireless-info.txt](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9331792/)

Ran the script but I can't see anything in the output that points me at the solution.

Comment: It appears you have two Ethernet controllers, is that correct? What wireless device came with your laptop? Do you have any kind of VPN or another virtual device?

Comment: Wired and wireless.  The Broadcom wireless came with the Laptop.  The wired works fine if I hook it to the router which probably should tell me something.  No Virtualization software installed.

Comment: Have you checked the settings such as possibly setting a static IP? Maybe your DHCP client is looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Well, I think I have.  Static IPs was a problem on some of my PCs and other Linux boxes when I upgraded my router but I don't believe I ever had this build configured for static addresses.  Ifconfig looks right.  Only thing I don't understand is what is in resolv.conf.  Not sure what uses that file or whether what is there is correct.  Something I am still investigating.

Comment: Did you try to connect your laptop directly to the router with a cable? See if that works first. It might not be a problem with your wireless at all.

Comment: Yes, I have done so.  Connecting with a cable works perfectly.  So, that means to me that it is definitely something in the wireless path.  Probably not anything DNS related or [it seems to me ] the wired connection would not have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the driver you've installed is incorrect for your 14e4:4727 device. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
apt-get update
apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
echo brcmsmac >> /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot and your wireless should be operating correctly.

Comment: OK. That worked.  Thanks.  Impressive.  I was heading down this path myself but didn't have enough knowledge to put the commands together to get this result.  I was thrown off track when I looked at this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers.  It indicated for my situation 14e4:4727 that I should have been OK.  I am puzzled how I ever got this working in the first place but I did.  I swear.  What did you see that pointed you to this other driver, the b43 versus the wl?

Comment: Glad it's working. What I saw was the pci.id of 14e4:4727 and my experience.