# Cannot connect to network after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, networking, upgrade

Hi guys please I am new to ubuntu, I recently upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 14.10 from 14.04. Before this upgrade things were working perfectly fine.

Currently, It looks like my graphics drivers are not installed and I cannot connect to the internet through wire/wireless. On the keyboard the light indicator shows that the wireless is off but pressing the button makes no difference. I have pasted a diagnostic report [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9412420/) for your review

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/555397/wireless-connects-but-does-not-work/555531#555531

Comment: @chili555 unfortunately in my case I cannot connect either through nor wireless. My laptop is completely offline

Comment: Let's see how far we can get offline; please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and tell us if it's working. If not, please post another diagnostic report and I'll edit this question to propose a solution.

Comment: Still the same thing

Comment: And do you have an updated diagnostic report as above?